# How do you push a string into all users documents in a mongodb collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

This is my subcommand code:

```js
.addSubcommand(subcommand =>
  subcommand
  .setName('announcement')
  .setDescription('Announce something to every user. ')
  .addStringOption(option =>
    option
    .setName('announcement1')
    .setDescription('Announcement content')
    .setRequired(true))),
```

This is my code so far for the command:

```
if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'announcement') {
    const ann = interaction.options.getString('announcement1')
    const notificationschema = require('./schemas/notificationschema')

}
```

I am trying to push the contents of the variable ann into everyone's notificationschema into the notifs array.

How would I do this?

This is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const notificationschema = mongoose.Schema({

        User:String,
        Notifs:Array,
        Read:Boolean,

        
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('notification', notificationschema, 'notification')
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to store the notification in a notification table, and just remember which notifications each user has seen?  You don't really want to rewrite every document in your database for each notification, do you?  That will be horrible.

Comment: Wdym? Can u please elaborate? The way we were thinking is, the notification would be put into each user's document and the first command they run, they would see the notification pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `find` function from mongoose, then loop through all the found results.

```
const foundSchemas = await notificationSchema.find({});

foundSchemas.forEach(result => {
result.Notifs.push('Your Notification');
result.save();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **for looping function**:

First, call your index:

```js
const notificationschema = require('./schemas/notificationschema');
const notifs = await notificationschema.find({})
//This will make your data as array object.
```

Now After creating and calling your index. Use **for loop**:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < notifs.length; i++) {
  notificationschema.updateOne({
    User: notifs[i].memberID //I assume that this column is a member_id
  }, {
    $push: {
      Notifs: "Something you wanted to say here or whatsoever"
    }
  })
}
```